# Eigen Templated Function and Dimensions

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a function of the form

```
template <typename derived>
void foo(Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& z){
  nc = z.cols();
  nr = z.rows();
  Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> x(nr-1, nc);
}
```

I want a function that is somewhat like the above pseudo-ish code. Essentially I want to pass an object z which can be either a VectorXd or MatrixXd object, if its a MatrixXd object then I want to define x as a MatrixXd of dimension (nr-1) x nc. However, if z is a VectorXd object I want to define x as a VectorXd object of length (nr-1).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Eigen::DenseBase<>` is an abstract base class, you cannot create any object of such types. What you're looking for is:

```
typename Derived::PlainObject x(nr-1, nc);
```

Comment: would that work for vectors as well? (as I mentioned was the key problem)

Comment: @jds That would work, as long as the number of rows in `Derived` is not fixed at compile time.